# Dynamic sorting for gridview populated from EF at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a gridview that I'm populating at runtime:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" OnSorted="GridView1_Sorted"
        OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        <Columns>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }

private void LoadData()
    {
        TSCDB = new TSCDB();

        GridView1.DataSource = TSCDB.TsCiTAllOrders
            .Where(x => x.DeletedDate == null && x.StatusName != "Cancelled")
            .AsEnumerable()
            .ToList();

        GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
        GridView1.PageSize = 10;
        GridView1.AllowSorting = true;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

I'm trying to enable sorting on the grid, however this code isn't working when I click on a column header:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        var sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
        var sortDirection = e.SortDirection;

        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Sort(sortExpression, sortDirection);
    }
```

This obviously just loops between the Sort & DataBind statements, but amazingly, I can't seem to find clear cut instructions on the Google machine.

Comment: Could you add `AllowSorting="true"` to ASPX instead of `Page_Load` event? E.g. `<asp:GridView AllowSorting="true"`

Comment: I could, is there a difference in the methods?  I'm asking because I don't know.  I'm learning asp.